# JavaFX start method for a hello world button not allowing to setText or add setOnAction

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to get some practice in with javaFX, and I just wanted to see if I could get a simple button to be created and prepared with a setOnAction enabled. However, the btn does not have the .setText method aand the EventHandler gives an error on ActionEvent saying that ActionEvent is not bound and should extend Event.

I am following countless tutorials and this should be what everyone is doing for their buttonsetup, but it is falling apart. I am using 1.7_45, so JavaFX is supported. I also enabled the JavaFX support plugin in IDEA.

```
 //package ;
import javafx.*;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class OptionsToggleMenu  {



public OptionsToggleMenu() {
}

 public void launch(String... args){

 }

 @Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    final Button btn = new Button();
     btn.setText("hello world");


   //btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");

    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            btn.setText("changed");
        }
    });
 }
```

}

Comment: Please show the whole class, including imports.

Comment: You are using `java.awt.Button` and `java.awt.ActionEvent` instead of the JavaFX classes. Remove all the awt and swing imports.

Comment: Your button isn't added to the scene pls check oracle hello world before asking https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/hello_world.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing javafx and swing - you will need to correct your imports.